# How to permanently disable mobile data on a rooted Android device?

Tags: root-access, internet

Hi guys I was hoping for some guidance on disabling my mobile data on my rooted Android. I've tried locating a file do delete with ES explorer, but I'm honestly unsure if there is such a separate file to disable the data and keep my call function on. Any help at all would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use your phone's test page to disable it... It's like disabling an adapter on a computer are its devices software it will still look like it's on but you can change your way you speak to your tower from like 5 seconds 10 seconds 30 seconds and disabled or immediate. I use phone dialer to pull up the test page `*#*#4636#*#*`